# Why there are no username/email update in ion_auth?

Tags: php, codeigniter, ion-auth

I am using `ion_auth` with CI3 and I am in the process that the user can update their own account. And I found out that there's no capability for the user to update their username or email. Is it intended that way for security or I need to include those fields in the user update?

Comment: You should extend form for user edit. It is in `APPPATH . 'views/auth/edit_user.php'` file. Corresponding controller/method would be `edit_user($id)` method of Auth controller. There are missing fields for username and/or email. Change your form and controller to fit your needs.